# How do I add a gradient fill to a movie clip in as3 flash

Tags: movieclip

trying to make code to first addchild movie clip, then apply a gradient to it.  Some posts have talked about making a gradient box the same as the bounding area of the movie clip and add a mask which would be great but I'm getting no where.  Code I'm using is more confusing then anything if I posted every thing I tried.  Wouldn't have to be a movieclip, could have it be a button or graphic.

Comment: ...then try to understand it, *programmer,* for what good would it do to post questions on **how to do this** and **what does this do?**

Answer (score 0):

Use `MovieClip.graphics.beginGradientFill(fillType, colors);`

For example,

`yourMovieClip.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR, [0XFF0000, 0XC0C0C0])`

will make your MovieClip a linear gradient of red and a grayish color, and you can change the `SpreadMethod` to, for example, `REPEAT`, `REFLECT`, or `PAD` (`SpreadMethod.type`).

See the [Adobe LiveDocs Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#beginGradientFill%28%29) of it.

Also, before you ask, you need to import Classes from `flash.display`.